# Set option list height of a dropdown list

Tags: html, css

Right now i have about 100 options in my list (HTML Dropdown list) and as it shows around 10 options and the rest on scroll.

What i need is to reduce the height of options list ie. up on clicking the dropdown, show 3 options and rest on scroll.

I will really appreciate you if you could able to answer this or direct me to a possible solution.

Thanks in advance,

Tismon Varghese

Answer (score 2):

You can use `size="5"` attribute.

It will display 5 options for example.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But this will set the default dropdown list height. What i need is to reduce the pop-down list height. (if the default number of items is 10 and rest on scroll, i need to make 3 and rest on scroll.)